# Pulling json data from a web server into text

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, get

Hi all I've been stuck on this issue for a while. I am currently using dojo.xhrget to put the json data onto my html page as text. At the moment I keep getting the error on safari, it doesn't seem to respond to other browsers due to cross domain issues i believe -

```
" An unexpected error occurred: RequestError: Unable to load 171.51.21.41:3000/information.json status: 0"
```

I have attempted to use dojo.io.script, but it still comes up blank. I suspect for some reason it cannot read my json data - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require(["dojo"], function(dojo){

dojo.ready(function(){
// Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
var targetNode = dojo.byId("licenseContainer");

// The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
var xhrArgs = {
url: "171.51.21.41:3000/information.json ",
handleAs: "json",
load: function(data){
  // Replace newlines with nice HTML tags.
  data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");

  // Replace tabs with spaces.
  data = data.replace(/\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

  targetNode.innerHTML = data;
},
error: function(error){
  targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
}
}

 // Call the asynchronous xhrGet
 var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
});

});
```

I borrowed this code & edited. I know the error statement comes up because of the error 
function; but I wish to know why & how I can access the json.

thanks in advance~

Snippet of my JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"Field":"Devices","Phase":"Final","Name":"MP3 Player"}]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the data from a different domain than you are on?

Comment: Is your information.json a valid json file ?

Comment: yes that seems to be the issue with the other growers but safari shows the error function which I think it means it can possibly access it.

Comment: I've put a snippet on the question @PhilippeBoissonneault .. I believe it is valid.

Comment: do you need to put `http://` in your xhrArgs url?

Comment: @PatrickGunderson maybe you should post this as an answer, so he can accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put `http://` in your xhrArgs url